# Show approved strings

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show an ad if its approved = 1. What I'm using is this code;

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE approved = '1'");
$ad = $db->fetch_array($query);

if (advert_available())
{
    for($id=1; $id < 4+1; ++$id)
    {
        if ($ad['spot_id'] == $id)
        {
            // Approved ad
            $ads = '<td width="25%" valgn="middle" align="center"><a href="'.htmlspecialchars_uni($ad['link']).'" target=_blank><img src="'.htmlspecialchars_uni($ad['image']).'" alt="" title="" width="285px" height="114px" class="advert_image"></a></td>';
        }
        else
        {
            // If ad is not approved, show default <td>
            $ads = '<td width="25%" valgn="middle" align="center"><a href="misc.php?action=buy_ad&amp;spot_id='.$id.'"><img src="images/xf/ads1.gif" alt="Ad Spot" title="Click here to reserve this ad spot."></a></td>';
        }
        $ads_spot_bit .= $ads;
    }

    $ads_spot = '
        <table border="0" class="tborder">
            <tr>
                '.$ads_spot_bit.'
            </tr>
        </table>
    ';
}
```

But the issue is, it only shows one approved ad, however there are 2 approved ads! What I'm missing here?

BY the way, I'm using for loop to show 4 ad spots.

Comment: You need to call `$db->fetch_array()` (or an equivalent) repeatedly, handling an ad on each occasion, until there are no more records / you have everything you need.

Comment: you call from db where approved is 1. so, why do you still check if `$ad['spot_id'] == $id` ?

Comment: Actually, I do not want to use a new sql query for each ad spot to check. That would make extra server load.

Is there any other option?

Comment: @aacanakin: Because I'm using for loop, and if the spot_id == $id then it should show the approved ad. otherwise it should show the default <td>

Comment: @Umar the question is marked as solved when an answer is accepted - it's not necessary or a good idea to put "SOLVED" In the question title.

Comment: Thankyou AD7six, I was unaware about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put in the following condition

```
 if ($ad['spot_id'] == $id)
```

There may be 2 possible active ads but the spot_id coming from the database may not be matching the $id column from the for loop.

Comment: You're right Sarfraz. Unfortunately I've to use sql query inside for loop. Its making 4 extra queries though but its the only solution I thought. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the result in a loop. Try something like this

```
while( $ad = $db->fetch_array($query) ){
  //do your processing
}
```

Comment: But in this case I probably wouldn't be able to show X amount of ad spots, I've set that option in backend by the way as to how many ad spots admin would like to show on header.

That's why I want to stick to for loop.